# Binary Tree branch sums without recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to calculate a sum of each branch of a binary tree without using recursion. I'm trying to use a stack and can't figure out how to fix my code to get the right sums.

```
public static List<Integer> branchSums(BinaryTree root) {
    LinkedList<BinaryTree> toVisit = new LinkedList<>();
    BinaryTree current = root;
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum = 0;

    while (current != null || !toVisit.isEmpty()) {
        while (current != null) {
            sum += current.value;
            toVisit.push(current);
            current = current.left;
        }

        current = toVisit.pop();

        // if found leaf add sum to results and decrement sum by current node
        if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
            sums.add(sum);
            sum -= current.value;
        }

        current = current.right;
    }

return sums;
}
```

Example input:

```
         1
      /      \
     2        3
   /   \    /   \
  4     5  6     7
 / \   /
8   9 10
```

Example output [15, 16, 18, 10, 11]

Comment: could you give an example of a tree and expected output? question is not clear and since your code does not reflect answer it leaves the question as unclear

Comment: The first thing you should do is write a comment at the beginning of the loop describing what's supposed to be on the stack at that point, and what nodes are supposed to be in `sum`, and what's left to do.  Then make sure it's true for every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted this for fun and was surprised I didn't see any actual solutions.  The following is in Kotlin but can easily be transcribed into Java.  The trick was to add state to the Node itself to mark it as consumed before you popped it, otherwise there was no value there to check when going down another branch.

This might be useful in super rare cases to prevent stack overflow?  This will still run in O(N) but takes more space with the stacks, and will visit a node twice, once to traverse and once to pop.

```
    open class BinaryTree(value: Int) {
    var value = value
    var left: BinaryTree? = null
    var right: BinaryTree? = null
    var consumed: Boolean = false
}

fun branchSums(root: BinaryTree): List<Int> {
    var sumList = ArrayList<Int>()
    var nodeStack = ArrayList<BinaryTree>()
    var valueStack = ArrayList<Int>()

    nodeStack.add(root)

    while(!nodeStack.isEmpty()) {
        val node = nodeStack.get(nodeStack.size-1)

        if (node.consumed) {
            valueStack.removeAt(valueStack.size - 1)
            nodeStack.removeAt(nodeStack.size - 1)
            continue
        }

        valueStack.add(node.value)

        if (node.right == null && node.left == null) {
            var sum = 0
            for (value in valueStack) {
                sum += value
            }
            sumList.add(sum)
        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            nodeStack.add(node.right!!)
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            nodeStack.add(node.left!!)
        }

        node.consumed = true
    }

    return sumList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Issue with your code is you are not keeping track of the node which
>   has been last popped from your stack.

Here is the updated code:

```
public static List<Integer> caculateSum(BinaryTree root) {
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
    int sum=0;
    BinaryTree current = root, popped=null;
    Stack<BinaryTree> s = new Stack<BinaryTree>();
    while(current!=null ) {
        //checking if last node popped from stack is not equal to left or right node of current node
        if(popped==null||((current.left!=null && !current.left.equals(popped)) && (current.right!=null && !current.right.equals(popped)))) {
            while(current != null) {
                sum+=current.value;
                s.push(current);
                current = current.left;

            }
        }
        current=s.peek();
        if(current.right == null) {
            //if current node is leaf node
            if(current.left == null) {
                sums.add(sum);
            }
            sum-=current.value;
            popped = current;
            s.pop();
        } else if(current.right!=null && current.right.equals(popped)){
            //if current node both left and right nodes have been processed
            sum-=current.value;
            popped = current;
            s.pop();
        }else {
            //if current node right part is not processed
            sum+=current.right.value;
            s.push(current.right);  
        }
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        current=s.peek();       
    }   
    return sums;
}
```

Will explain this by taking an example. Suppose we have given binary tree

1,2,9,3,7,null,8,5

Here in above code apart from old variables a new variable `popped` is used which **keeps track of last element which is popped out from stack**.

So, following are the major steps :

1. Starting from `current` node first we are checking if current node left is not equal to popped (if it is equal it means that `current` node left part is already processed so we don't need to process it again). Same we are checking if `current` node right node is not equal to `popped` node (if it is equal it means we have already processed right node of `current` node  which indirectly means `left` node is also processed).
2. Now for the top node of stack which is `current` node we check :

   - If its `right` node is null  If it is true it means either `current`
     node is leaf node or it is an already processed node whose `right`
     node is null (like in our example node with value of 3).   If it is
     leaf we add it in our `sums` list.  Also, for both cases we remove
     this `top` node and subtract its value from current   `sum` value
     (This thing has been done in above code as well) .Along with this we
     will   keep track of popped element from stack in `popped` variable.
   - If its right is not null but its `right` node is equal to `popped`
     node   This happens when in last pass of while loop we had processed
     this `right` node.  This means for top node of stack both left and
     right node have been processed and hence we pop this node and keep
     track of it in `popped` variable.
   - Else we push the right node of top element of stack in stack.

At the end for above example , `sums` variable will store result as [11, 10, 18]

Comment: Your code results in infinite loop, but I will consider the idea of popped and try it in my code

Comment: With which example you have tried because I have checked with above example and it worked fine .

Answer (score 1):

You can have this method:

```
 public static int getBranchSum(Node root){
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);
    int sum=0;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {            
        Node curNode = q.poll();
        sum+=curNode.data;
        if(curNode.left==null || curNode.right==null)
            curNode.visited=true;
        if(curNode.left != null && curNode.left.visited)
            curNode.visited=true;
        if(curNode.left!=null && !curNode.left.visited)
            q.add(curNode.left);
        else if(curNode.right!=null && !curNode.right.visited)
            q.add(curNode.right);
    }
    root.visited=false;
    return sum;
}
```

Then call it below in a while loop as long as the output is not equal the root data.

```
    boolean flag=true;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(flag){
        int result =getBranchSum(root);
        if(result == root.data)
            flag=false;
        else
            list.add(result);
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

However the above the working only if we have a visited boolean in the node:

```
class Node{
Node left,right;
int data;
boolean visited = false;
Node(int data){
    this.data=data;
    left=right=null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Branch sum without recursion

```py
def branchSums(root):
    cs=0
    stack=[{"node":root,"cs":cs}]
    sums=[]
    while(len(stack)>0):
        node_info=stack.pop()
        node,cs=node_info["node"],node_info["cs"]
        if node is None:
            continue
        cs=cs+node.value
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            sums.append(cs)
            print(sums)
        stack.append({"node":node.right,"cs":cs})
        stack.append({"node":node.left,"cs":cs})

    return sums
```